# Alterar nome de um Controller sem perder informações

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho um Controller chamado Home e estou querendo alterar o mesmo para BPA.

Quero saber se basta eu alterar o nome `HomeController` para `BpaController` e alterar o nome da pasta Home na pasta View.

Ou se preciso alterar algo mais para funcionar sem dar problemas.

Comment: Depende da sua configuração, mas pro básico, é provável que sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para alterar o nome de uma classe e suas referências, sugiro que **altere o nome do arquivo** pelo **Visual Studio** na **Solution Explorer**, assim, ele irá perguntar se deseja também **alterar todas as referências daquela classe**, fazendo todo o processo automaticamente para ti.

Será alterado todas as referências `HomeController`, porém, você deverá alterar as referências à palavra `Home` manualmente.

Comment: Ele alterou tudo o que tinha escrito `HomeController`, onde tinha apenas `Home`, tive que alterar na mão mesmo. Mas valeu pela dica.